# Why isn't my list elements getting casted to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, casting, integer

[image: casting function]

(I wrote list instead of the actual list names for better understanding)

I'm reading from a file with one number at each line. Then I made it into a `list[]` and I did `list.append(line.replace("\n", "").strip())`

When executing the function I wrote - `list = inteles(list)`

I tried restarting vs code, but it didn't work.

Comment: Because that's not how names work in Python. They do not work like variables in C. Please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns).

Comment: @timgeb This wouldn't work in C, either. You'd need to use pointers in C to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `list.append(int(line.replace("\n", "").strip()))`

Comment: It is for a coding class and the teacher specified that we can't merge the file reading and casting functions. I think it's pretty unreasonable, but he will take away points for not doing so :(

Answer (score 0):

Since when you say `for x in y`, the `x` you get isn't able to change the value of the real `x` in the list. (except with modifying class attributes I believe)

To fix this, just do a list comprehension:

```py
def inteles(lista):
  return [int(ele) for ele in lista]
```

Comment: The explanation could be better, but yes, it has to do with mutable/immutable objects and assignments never mutate - plus ``sor`` (in OP's code) is not "**the element**", but just a name, *pointing* to an object. Edit: [the vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) posted by @timgeb explains this in more detail

Comment: @MikeScotty talking about mutability when trying to explain assignment is often misguided. Assignment works the same for all types. `int(ele)` creates a new integer, and then OP's code creates a name `sor` for that `int` which is reassigned as soon as the `for` loop enters the next iteration. No mutability needed in the explanation. (Except for the fact that `int(x)` never mutates `x`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of the original list, you are not creating a new list either, you are just changing the value of a local variable (to that function). If you want to get a list with all strings converted to a integer, you should create a new list in the function and append the changed local variable to that local list and then return that local list.

Below is a example of that:

```
foist = [1, 3, "4", "72"]

def inteles(lista):
    newlist = []
    for sor in lista:
        sor = int(sor)
        newlist.append(sor)

    return(newlist)
```